# Compress Image automatically using a prefixed link

Tags: css, angularjs, image, compression, ionic-framework

I am starting to develop a mobile application and have some issues with the images.

In fact I am transforming an existing website to a mobile app, so I am using the existing database with the existing pictures too.

The problem is that the images have a really good quality (5MB each) and I have more than 100 images to include on the app.

Is there any website who can transform the image online and give a link.

For example the image is here

```
http://myWebSite.com/img1.jpeg
```

I want a website like that

```
http://compressWebSite/myWebSite.com/img1.jpeg
```

PS : I don't have access to the website server to optimise the images. I have only access to the link of each image from the database.

Comment: not hard to research how to optimize images

Comment: @charlietfl as I said I don't have access to the server to modify the images I have only access to the link !

Comment: @aBennouna, I don't really get what is it that you want to do. When you say "transform", what do you mean? Do you mean transform to another type of image? And when you say "Optimise", do you mean "Compress"?

Comment: @Kiong. I mean compress,instead of having hundreds of 5MB images, I want to have images of 100kb for example. I can't do it manually I have to do it by code because I don't have access to the server to modify the images.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say, your requirements are

- Only have URL of the images
- Want to send the URL of the images to a service to compress the size down (with similar image quality)
- Reference just the compressed image URL

If thats the case, you can refer to [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/developers) or [Kraken.io](https://kraken.io/docs/integration-url) services

Comment: Thanks @Kiong , I will test this later ant let you know !